# Change html style after submitting form

Tags: php, html, css, forms

Is there a way to change the style of something from display none to display block after a form has been submitted? I'm checking if the form has been submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

I'm guessing it goes somewhere after here..?

I've tried this but no joy...

```
echo '<style type="text/css">
      .login {
       display: block;
      } </style>';
```

thanks

Comment: Add your full code....

Comment: add CSS like this from php is not a good thinq. You can Change Style With JS !

Comment: You could also assign it a different class, one showing the form and one hiding it, and then apply the class accordingly with php.

Comment: @ssbb not allways you can use JS!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably define a style for hidden, and then add/remove that class from the parent element.

So in css:

```
<style type="text/css">
hidden{
  display:none;
} 
</style>
```

Then in your code something like:

```
$submitted = isset($_POST['submit']);
```

And when you render your form:

```
<div class="<?=($submitted)?'':'hidden'; ?>">
    <form...
</div>
```

Alternatively, just don't render the form at all:

```
<?if(!$submitted){?>
<form...
<?}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would tell you to add on your `<form>` an onsubmit: 
`<form onsubmit="DisplayLogin()">`

And elsewhere some JS

```
<script>
function DisplayLogin(){
    $('.login').css('display','block'); //using jquery
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the piece of jQuery below should work for you, but it's very difficult because you didn't include a lot of code. Replace `button` with the button's `id` or `class`.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.login').css('display', 'block');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/grmpnsq9/)

Comment: This will not work because the button i am using is a submit on a form and so the page refreshes. Once it refreshes it sets the css style back to the original...

Comment: Ok, this information is missing from your question, as is a lot of other information, making it very difficult for us to come with a fitting answer. Maybe you can send a parameter in the URL after the form is submitted and then, if that parameter is present, hide or show what you want to hide or show. https://www.google.dk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=send%20url%20parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```html
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
<!--here you close the php tag-->
<style type="text/css">
      .login {
             display: block;
      }
</style>
<!--here you open the php tag-->
}
```